# Asp.net c# to read word document line by line

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string line;
string path = UploadContacts.PostedFile.FileName;
var reader = new StreamReader(path);

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var link = line;

    if (link != string.Empty)
    {
        // another functionality ;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Here `UploadContacts` is the file upload control. I am uploading a doc file through this. My aim is to read each line by line of word document and get into another functionality but it not working.

Throwing exception `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\tr.docx'.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that exception definitive enough?

Comment: A Word document is not a plain text document, so you won't be able to read anything with your approach, even if you get your streaming to work correctly (put it into a Stream).

Comment: @sphair, you would be correct if it was a `.doc`, but `.docx` is XML and therefore can be read as a plain text document

Comment: @freefaller: docx is a zip file, where its internal files are in xml format. It's not so simple. That said, I think the OP wants to read the document's content, and reading the xml won't be very useful. FYI, the OpenXML SDK can help you to extract relevant parts of the document

Comment: The issue is caused the FileName property that contains the client side file name. Not the server side. You should first save the file somewhere, or, better, read from the PostedFile.InputStream property

Comment: This might work as well: new StreamReader(UploadContacts.PostedFile.FileContent)

Comment: @Sphair PostedFile does not contain a property with PostedContent

Comment: InputStream or whatever then - look up the MSDN docs :)

Comment: Thanks @SteveB, I stand corrected... apologies sphair

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read line by line use the following code:

```
// Loop through all lines in the document.

Application application = new Application();
Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\new folder\\word.docx");
                   String read = string.Empty;
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
            if (temp != string.Empty)
                data.Add(temp);
        }
        // Close word.
        application.Quit();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file on the users computer or the server that hosting your web application?

Since you said the user is uploading a file I get the impression that the user is selecting a path on their machine.  Remember that your c# code is executing on a server someplace else.  It can't directly access the users machine (unless it's on a shared network).

In the past I have used the [plupload jquery control](http://www.plupload.com/) when I have needed to have users upload files to my web applications.  Very simple to use with mvc.  Here is someone elses stack overflow question that will help you figure out how to use it... [Using plupload with MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094296/using-plupload-with-mvc3)